# How to fix ‘Trying to get property of non-object ’ notice in Previous Post Thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a thumbnail for next and previous post in my Wordpress theme specifically inside the `single.php` file.

It works as require but it is displaying the notice:

> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in \wp-content\themes\theme\template-parts\content-footer.php on line 27

I have tried out some of the examples from similar answers in this website but they do not work for me. 
I removed both `$prevPost->ID` and `$nextPost->ID` but it then displays the current post thumbnail instead.

The code causing the error is below:
The line of code causing the notice is the **3rd** and **4th** lines below:

```
<?php 
    $prevPost = get_previous_post(); 
    $nextPost = get_next_post(); 
    $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(50,50) );  
    $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(50,50) );  
?>
```

The thumbnails were called using the codes below:

`<div class="uk-width-auto"><?php echo $prevthumbnail; ?></div>` and `<div class="uk-width-auto"><?php echo $nextthumbnail; ?></div>` which both works.

The error is just a notice so it does not break the website or even appear unless wordpress debug is enabled. However, I would prefer not getting this notice so as not to cause some concern for my client.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: What does `var_dump($prevPost);` and `var_dump($nextPost);` display?

Comment: I just checked `var_dump($prevPost);` and it displays values for post_title, post_status, post_excerpt, etc but nothing related to image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in WordPress - the first post in the database is NOT going to have a "previous" post, and the last post is not going to have a "next" - so this behavior is perfectly normal.

To prevent the notice, you just need to check if it exists first - I typically like to use [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to perform the check - like so:

```
$prevPost = get_previous_post(); 
$nextPost = get_next_post(); 
if ( ! empty( $prevPost->ID ) ) {
    $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(50,50) );  
}

if ( ! empty( $nextPost->ID ) ) {
    $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(50,50) );  
}
```

Note that this may have the undesirable effect of leaving `$nextthumbnail` and / or `$prevthumbnail` as undefined variables, so to combat that, I'd recommend modifying the code even further:

```
$prevPost = get_previous_post(); 
$nextPost = get_next_post(); 
// use a ternary to set the thumbnail if not empty, or empty string if empty
$prevthumbnail = ( empty( $prevPost->ID ) ) ? '' : get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(50,50) );  
// use a ternary to set the thumbnail if not empty, or empty string if empty
$nextthumbnail = ( empty( $nextPost->ID ) ) ? '' : get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(50,50) );
```

Comment: Wouldn't `if ( ! empty( $prevPost->ID ) )` throw an error as well if `$prevPost` isn't an object? (Honest question, I haven't checked myself.)

Comment: Nope.  That's the beauty of [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and `isset` - it does NOT throw an error in the process of evaluating if it's empty / set.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that! I got to learn something new today, thanks!

Comment: I used the second code and the notice is now gone. Thank you!